# Where is the body tag in this WordPress theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, genesis

I need to add the ID 'skrollr-body' to the body tag of my website but I can't find the opening body tag anywhere. Its a very simple change I know, but the website isn't mine and directory structure is very messy and he's asked me to resolve the issue of the website not scrolling on mobile/tablet (which is due to the body tag not having the ID 'skrollr-body').

The theme inherits from Genesis, and in the header.php I found this which does mention the body tag, can I add an ID in this snippet of code at all ? -

```
genesis_markup( array(
    'html5'   => '<body %s>',
    'xhtml'   => sprintf( '<body class="%s">', implode( ' ', get_body_class() ) ),
    'context' => 'body',
) );
```

Also, the header.php in the theme it self has nothing to do with the opening body tag:

```
<div class="one-third first">
    <a href="">
        <img src="" />
        <img src="" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="two-thirds">
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="callus">
        <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if this was a static site instead of a dynamic site with a CMS it would be easiest change possible, but this WordPress directory is so messy and disorganised I can't locate the tag at all.

I almost thought about implementing some jQuery to amend the tag but that seems a bit over the top for such a simple change.

Cheers.

Comment: In `xhtml` part you have [`get_body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class). Here you can add your own class.

Comment: I unfortunately HAVE to use an ID for the plugin to work correctly, can I change the code slightly to use an ID instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
genesis_markup( array(
    'html5'   => '<body %s>',
    'xhtml'   => sprintf( '<body id="skrollr-body" class="%s">', implode( ' ', get_body_class() ) ),
    'context' => 'body',
) );
```

Or with this:

```
genesis_markup( array(
    'html5'   => '<body id="skrollr-body" %s>',
    'xhtml'   => sprintf( '<body id="skrollr-body" class="%s">', implode( ' ', get_body_class() ) ),
    'context' => 'body',
) );
```

Comment: I've actually tried this already prior to posting the question and it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Hey Dingo! The second snippet worked, cheers! (well it does on mobile, ill check tablet now!)

Comment: Great :) It should be working on tablet if it does on mobile :) If this helped, feel free to marked it as solved

Comment: Marked as solved, was just waiting for it to let me use the 'tick' after the countdown! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the theme you've got is a bit mangled - it's rare to find (or need) a header.php in the child theme of the Genesis Framework.

The correct way to add `<body>` attributes is with the filter that Genesis provides:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_body', 'so3707332_attributes_body' );
/**
 * Add ID attribute to body element.
 *
 * @param array $attributes Existing attributes.
 *
 * @return array Amended attributes.
 */
function so3707332_attributes_body( $attributes ) {
    $attributes['id'] = 'skrollr-body';

    return $attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can find the body tag inside the header.php file of your theme..
replace this:

```
genesis_markup( array(
    'html5'   => '<body %s>',
    'xhtml'   => sprintf( '<body class="%s">', implode( ' ', get_body_class() ) ),
    'context' => 'body',
) );
```

with:

```
genesis_markup( array(
    'html5'   => '<body %s>',
    'xhtml'   => sprintf( '<body class="%s">', implode( ' ', get_body_class('classname') ) ),
    'context' => 'body',
) );
```

reply if it worked.

Best of luck.

Comment: I'm trying to add an ID, not change the class!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the ID to the `sprintf` statement.

```
'xhtml'   => sprintf( '<body id="skrollr-body" class="%s">', implode( ' ', get_body_class() ) ),
```